# Using GlSurfaceview in activity

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-view, glsurfaceview

I have an Activity and i had set activity's content view as "R.layout.main.xml".And i have an another class which contains animation created using openGL. Now i need to use this animation in the background of the Activity.

The code is like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_pixie);

    mGLView = new ClearGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mGLView);
 }
```

But my app is Crashing ..How can i solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the `setContentView()` a second time, you replace what had been set the first time, leaving you with only the background. The crash is most likely because you depend on the elements in the main layout, which is removed.

Rather than calling `setContentView()` twice, you should include the `GLSurfaceView` in the main layout. Below is an example of how this can be done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent>
    <your.application.package.ClearGLSurfaceView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    <!--put the rest of your layout here, i.e the contents of the original R.layout.main_pixie-->
</FrameLayout>
```

Then you can load this layout in your `onCreate()` as usual (main_pixie_new refers to the above xml, I just gave it that name to keep things as clear as possible):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_pixie_new);
 }
```